# Undeclared identifier initializing a frame

Tags: objective-c

I'm trying to init a frame. Here is the code. I don't understand why I get from Xcode the message `Undeclared identifier _frame`. It is in the .h file and I call it in the implementation with its name. Where do I wrong?

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface BNRHypnosisView : UIView

@property (nonatomic) CGRect _frame;

@end


#import "BNRHypnosisView.h"

@implementation BNRHypnosisView

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];

    if (self) {
        _frame = frame;
    }

    return self;
}


@end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you declare a property called `_frame` (one underscore), Objective-C synthesizes a getter, a setter, and an instance variable called `__frame` (two underscores). Change your assignment to either use `self._frame` to access the property through the setter, or to use `__frame` to access the variable directly:

```
if (self) {
    __frame = frame;
}
```

Even better, rename the property to something with no underscores, to be consistent with how Apple recommends to name properties.

Answer (score 2):

First of all,  don't declare a variables that your class already has.
And second thing. Why you hold frame? Your `BNRHypnosisView` is subclass of `UIView` which already has
`@property(nonatomic) CGRect frame;`
property and you can access it any time!

Answer (score 0):

Change your declearation to..

```
@property (nonatomic) CGRect frame;
```

Hope it will solve your issue. It happened because previous one created an instance variable named `__frame` which contains 2 underscore.